# CSS file attached to Masterpage is causing error

Tags: 2010, master-page, css, style.css

The CSS file that I have linked in the head of my Masterpage is causing my home page to error. Im not using the default.aspx as my home page...not sure if that matters. When I remove the CSS link, the masterpage works fine.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: Error

File Not Found.


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: bc9ceee8-3110-4917-8cd6-ed48edbe36db

Date and Time: 10/19/2015 4:38:35 PM

Comment: Also, when I try to edit the Master page in SPD, i get an error that the feature has been turned off and see the SCA, but I am the SCA and it is turned on.

Comment: can you include the markup you are using to link the css file?